# What is the Kotlin equivalent of this Java class

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to convert the following Java class in Kotlin

```
abstract class BaseExpandedViewCreator implements NotificationViewCreator
{
   protected  RawNotification rawNotification;
   protected final Context context;

   BaseExpandedViewCreator(@NonNull Context context)
   {
       this.context = Objects.requireNonNull(context);
   }

  @Override
  public void setRawNotification(@NonNull RawNotification rawNotification)
  {
      this.rawNotification = rawNotification;
      initRawNotification(rawNotification);
  }

 /**
  * Override this function to initialise {@link RawNotification} for view creators if needed.
  */
 protected void initRawNotification(@NonNull RawNotification rawNotification) {}
 }
```

Kotlin interface

```
interface NotificationViewCreator {

   fun setRawNotification(rawNotification: RawNotification)
}
```

This is my implementation:

```
    abstract class BaseExpandedViewCreator(
        protected val context: Context
    ):NotificationViewCreator {

    var rawNotification: RawNotification ? = null

    fun setRawNotification(rawNotification: RawNotification) {
        this.rawNotification = rawNotification
        initRawNotification(rawNotification)
    }
     fun initRawNotification(rawNotification: RawNotification) {}
   }
```

I get the following error

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (setRawNotification(Lcom/myproject/RawNotification;)V): 
public final fun <set-rawNotification>(<set-?>: RawNotification): Unit defined in com.myproject.BaseExpandedViewCreator
public final fun setRawNotification(rawNotification: RawNotification): Unit defined in com.myproject.BaseExpandedViewCreator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change visibility of `var rawNotification` to `private` to avoid property/setter name clash:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseExpandedViewCreator(
        private val context: Context
): NotificationViewCreator {

    private lateinit var rawNotification: RawNotification // if you want non-nullable property
    // OR
    private var rawNotification: RawNotification? = null // if you are OK with nullable property

    override fun setRawNotification(rawNotification: RawNotification) {
        this.rawNotification = rawNotification
        initRawNotification(rawNotification)
    }

    fun initRawNotification(rawNotification: RawNotification) {}
}
```

Comment: it works, I prefer `lateinit var`